# Different behavior in Path fill for clockwise and counterclockwise paths

Tags: android, path, fill

It seems the path FILL_AND_STROKE behaves differently depending on which way I draw the path.

How can I make these fill completely? First one is clockwise, second is counterclockwise.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBmOP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy hack to make it work: instead of FILL_AND_STROKE, draw it twice using FILL first and then STROKE:

```
canvas.drawPath(mPath, paintFill);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, paintStroke);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint. If there is just a single path then FILL_AND_STROKE works fine, but when adding additional paths to it then the direction matters. 
I've had the same problem and managed to solve it by using

> Direction.CCW

when adding an additional shape to the path.

Also this is combined with

> path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD)

so that one can create a "hole" in another path.